# Are there any MathType clones for Open/Libre - Office?

Tags: software-rec, libreoffice, openoffice, word-processing

Are there any OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice equation editor/makers, similar to [MathType](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/MathType)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenOffice/LibreOffice already includes an equation editor, [Math](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/math/) ([Math](http://www.openoffice.org/product/math.html)). It's usable both as a standalone program and for equations embedded in a Write document.

There are two other major open-source mathematical document editors, both more directly inspired by [(La)TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). [LyX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX) is a wysiwyg front-end for LaTeX and lets you insert literal bits of LaTeX if you need it. If you're going to eventually learn LaTex to write documents with serious mathematical content, LyX provides a gentle curve to introduce you to the concepts before jumping into the syntax. Another contender is [TeXmacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeXmacs), which as the name suggests is inspired by both [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) and [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Emacs).

In terms of core functionality, they're all equivalent. They're all (MathType, OO Math, the Microsoft offering, LyX, TeXmacs, …) based on [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)'s design for TeX anyway. In terms of ergonomy, you'll have to make up your own mind.